# assigning specific column to be primary key when reflecting an existing table with sqlalchemy and turbogears

Tags: sqlalchemy, turbogears2

this is part of a project that involves working with tg2 against 2 databases one of them (which this model uses is mssql).  since that table I need to read/write from is created and managed with a different application I don't want turbogears to overwrite/change the table - just work with the existing table - so I use sqlalchemy magical 'autoload' reflection (I also don't know every detail of this table configuration in the mssql db)
some of the reflection is done in `model.__init__.py` and not in the class (as some sqlalchemy tutorial suggest) because of tg2 innerworking

this is the error message I get:(the table name in db is SOMETABLE and in my app the class is activities)

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper|Activities|SOMETABLE could not
 assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'SOMETABLE'
```

this is activities class:

```
class Activities(DeclarativeBase2):

    __tablename__ = 'SOMETABLE'
    #tried the classic way, I used in another place without tg but didn't work here -      the reflection should be outside the class
    #__table_args__=  {'autoload':True
                      #,'autoload_with':engine2
                     #}
    def __init__(self,**kw):
        for k,v in kw.items():
            setattr(self,k,v)
```

and this is `model.__init__.py` init model method (where the reflection is called):

```
def init_model(engine1,engine2):
    """Call me before using any of the tables or classes in the model."""
    DBSession.configure(bind=engine1)
    DBSession2.configure(bind=engine2)

    # If you are using reflection to introspect your database and create
    # table objects for you, your tables must be defined and mapped inside
    # the init_model function, so that the engine is available if you
    # use the model outside tg2, you need to make sure this is called before
    # you use the model.

    #
    # See the following example:
    metadata.bind = engine1
    metadata2.bind = engine2
    #metadata2=MetaData(engine2)

    global t_reflected
    #
    t_reflected = Table("SOMETABLE", metadata2,
        autoload=True, autoload_with=engine2)
    #
    mapper(Activities, t_reflected
```

so I think I need to tell sqlalchemy what is the primary key - but how do I do it while using the reflection (I know the primary key field)?

EDIT **the working solution**:

```
def init_model(engine1,engine2):
    """Call me before using any of the tables or classes in the model."""
    DBSession.configure(bind=engine1)
    DBSession2.configure(bind=engine2)

    # If you are using reflection to introspect your database and create
    # table objects for you, your tables must be defined and mapped inside
    # the init_model function, so that the engine is available if you
    # use the model outside tg2, you need to make sure this is called before
    # you use the model.

    #
    # See the following example:
    metadata.bind = engine1
    metadata2.bind = engine2
    #metadata2=MetaData(engine2)

    global t_reflected
    #
    t_reflected = Table("SOMETABLE", metadata2,String,primary_key=True),
        autoload=True, autoload_with=engine2)# adding the primary key column here didn't work
    #
    mapper(Activities, t_reflected, non_primary=True)# notice the needed non_primary - for some reason I can't do the whole mapping in one file and I Have to do part in init_model and part in the model - quite annoying
```

also in the model I had to add the primary key column making it:

```
class Activities(DeclarativeBase2):

__tablename__ = 'SOMETABLE'
#tried the classic way, I used in another place without tg but didn't work here -      the reflection should be outside the class
EVENTCODE = Column(String, primary_key=True)# needed because the reflection couldn't find the primary key .
```

of course I also had to add various imports in `model.__init__.py` to make this work

the strange thing is it turned out that it complained about not finding a primary key before it even connected to the db and when a standalone sqlalchemy class (without tg2) doing the same key - didn't complain at all.  makes you wonder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mix-and-match: see [Overriding Reflected Columns](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/schema.html?highlight=autoload#overriding-reflected-columns) in the documentation. In your case the code would look similar to this:

```
t_reflected = Table("SOMETABLE", metadata2,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True), # override reflected '???' column to have primary key
    autoload=True, autoload_with=engine2)
```

**edit-1: Model version:** I also think that only declarative version should work as well, in which case you should not define a table `t_reflected` and also should not map those manually using `mapper(...)` because declarative classes are automatically mapped:

```
class Activities(DeclarativeBase2):
    __table__ = Table('SOMETABLE', metadata2,
        Column('EVENTCODE', Unicode, primary_key=True),
        autoload=True, autoload_with=engine2,
    )
    def __init__(self,**kw):
        for k,v in kw.items():
            setattr(self,k,v)
```

Comment: thanks but something still doesn't work and I get the same error message (I'll edit what I did to the question)and some more mystery - when I use the class with autload and calling the engine directly without turbogears everything works! what am I doing wrong?

Comment: no this edit doesn't work - but you led me in the right path for a solution, I'll elobrate in an edit

Comment: explanation: this throws the error that started the whole thing - about not finding the engine . because in tg2 you have to define the reflection outside the class. (don't understand the inner working, just the way it works)